# How does the BackgroundWorker class fire its events on the UI thread?

Tags: .net, events, asynchronous, backgroundworker

I'm in the process of writing a asynchronous-operation manager somewhat similar to the [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class. I know that the `BackgroundWorker` does some internal voodoo (using the `AsyncOperation` class, from what I've read) to fire its events on the thread that created the `BackgroundWorker`, which is typically a UI thread.

My question is: what voodoo is necessary for events to get fired on a specific thread like the `BackgroundWorker` does?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is using [SynchronizationContext Class](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/SyncContextTutorial.aspx)

Comment: A terse answer, but linked to a verbose article. +1 and thanks. :)